# How to Use Marketing Cloud Data relationships to Populate an Email with data from 2 Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

Is it possible to use Data Relationships to Populate an email using data from 2 separate Data Extensions? I have made the data relationship between two Data Extensions - One Data Extension holds subscriber data and a Territory Attribute, the second data extensions holds a Reps name and territory. Therefore there is a common field.
What I want to be able to do is use attributes from both data extensions in an email without using Query or AMPScript.
While I can related the 2 Data Extensions, if I run a filter on the Subscriber Data Extensions using the Data Relationship I am filtering from a Data Extensions that does not have the Rep Name in it, so cannot use the rep name in the email???
Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to include data from related tables in email content:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/gtlDataRelationships.htm

For Example:

```
<html>
   <body>
      {{#=with Order_Details}}
          <h4 class="header">{{[First_Name]}} {{[Last_Name]}}, your order ID is {{OrderID}}</h4>
          <br />
              {{#=each Order_Details}}
                  {{#Products}}
                      <strong>Product Name:</strong> {{Product_Name}}<br />
                      <strong>SKU:</strong>{{sku}}<br />
                      <img src="{{Thumbnail_URL}}" /><br />
                      {{#Product_Ratings}}
                          <strong>Most Recent Review: </strong>{{Last_Review_Text}}<br />
                          <strong># of Ratings: </strong>{{Number_of_Ratings}}<br />
                          <strong>Ave Rating: </strong>{{Average_Rating}}<br /><br /><br />
                      {{/Product_Ratings}}
                  {{/Products}}
              {{/each}}
      {{/with}}
   <body>
</html>
```

The {{ }} tags are references to the DE's configured with a Data Relationship. Here, we can display data from the Product Ratings DE that relate to the Products DE that relate to the Order_Details DE which references the customer.

Comment: Thanks Muad'Dib.....I was looking for a way to do this without code. Appreciate the help though. The Data Relationships in the Drop Down menu in marketing cloud is to aid in filtering only

Comment: I am not able to understand how 4 data extensions are related to each other in above example and what to select at the time of send. I tried creating relation between two DEs with different column names having one field common (email). Not getting any data in resulting data extension after creating a data filter out of a data relationship. can you please shed some light on missing information? and what does {{=# means in above example. I can see that it is linking to a data extension but there are other DEs which are using {{# and which DE is going to be used at the time of send.

Answer (score 3):

After much effort and consultation with Marketing Cloud, this is not a feature of Marketing Cloud. It is possible only to filter by a related data extension but not possible to utilise the related data extensions attributes in an email.